# Test Class - Contract Creation, Null ContractNumber Field

Tags: unit-test, contracts

I'm working on developing a test class for my apex. I'm stuck with creation of Contract records contractnumber field.

In test class, I use the following code:

```
    Contract c = new Contract();
    c.Name = 'Test Contract';
    c.AccountId = acc.Id;
    c.Status = 'Draft';
    insert c;
    //I'm creating a draft contract and then activating it.
    c.status  = 'Activated';
    update c;
    system.debug('contract debug:'+c.contractnumber);
```

Contractnumber field on object is Autonumber, but in the log I get null for contractnumber.
I see the whole contract record is created with null ContractNumber.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As with all data that is updated during a DML operation, you must re-query this record in order to access any changes.

The only field that is automatically updated on an sObject instance is `Id`, when you perform an `insert` DML.